# Jcomponent paintcomponent not appearing on the panel

Tags: java, swing

i am making a simple GUI in which small boxes should appear on the `Jpanel` according to their x,y coordinates. So i in my structure i have got three classes:
1: `MyFrame` which contains the main `JFrame`
2: `MyPanel extends JPanel`
3: `Icon extends JComponent`

In my `MyFrame` i want to have a `MenuBar` through which i can open a file of X,Y coordinates and below the menu bar i want to have the `MyPanel` which will have all the `Icons` for each X,Y coordinates. The first problem i have is that the `Icon` do not appear on `MyPanel` when i add the Icons.

My code can be seen below:

```java
public class MyFrame {
    private JFrame frame;
    private MyPanel panel;

    public MyFrame(){
        panel = new MyPanel();
    }

    /*
    *HERE GOES THE `FILE OPEN` LISTENER
    * it creates `Coordinate` for each line 
    * passes the coordinate to panel.makeIcons()
    */

    public void createGui(){
      frame = new JFrame("Graph Editor");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setResizable(true);

      //create, get and set the Jframe menu bar
      //createMenuBar() returns a JMenuBar
      frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

      Container frame_pane = frame.getContentPane();

      panel.setBounds(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
      frame_pane.add(panel);

      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        MyFrame window = new MyFrame();
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {     
            public void run() {
                window.createGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Code For the panel for holding icons:

```java
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    private Set<Icon> points;

    public MyPanel(){
      setLayout(null);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
      setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }

    //gets called by `FILE OPEN` listener for each coordinate

    public void makeIcons(Coordinate obj){
        Icon temp = new Icon(obj);
        points.add(temp);

        //add the temp JComponent to this JPanel
        this.add(temp);
    }
}
```

Code for Icon which needs to be shown on the above panel:

```java
public Icon extends JComponent{
    private Coordinate location;
    public Icon(Coordinate obj){
        location = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(location.getX(), location.getY(), 20, 20);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(location.getX(), location.getY(), 20, 20);
    }
}
```

**First Problem:** The Icons do not show up in the panel with the above code.

**Second Problem:** When i change the `makeIcon` method in `MyPanel.class` to below. It shows the `Icons` By the `MenuBar` erases them when the `MenuBar` appears on any of the icons:

```java
public void makeIcons(Coordinate obj){
    Icon temp = new Icon(obj);
    points.add(temp);

    //add the temp JComponent to this JPanel
    this.add(temp);
    temp.paintComponent(this.getGraphics());
    revalidate();
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Don't call `paintComponent` (or any `paint`) method yourself, ever. This is not how painting works.  The core reasons why a component won't be paint is because - it's size is `0x0`; it's invisible; it's not added to a container that is (indirectly) added to a native peer. Based on my brief observation, I would say you're suffering from point number 1, in part due to the use of a `null` layout

Comment: My gut feeling would be to change `Icon` so that it wasn't a `Component` but was "paintable" and have `MyPanel` actually loop over them and paint them

Comment: @MadProgrammer you mean like completely remove the `paintComponent()` in the Icon class and put it in `MyPanel` and paint them?

Comment: Pretty much....

Comment: @MadProgrammer the problem is if i loop over the set of `Icons` should i define the `painComponent(g)` in the loop or just call `repaint()` method for each Icon in the set?

Comment: You also need to recognise that painting is done relative to the context of the component, where `0x0` is the top left corner of the component, so it doesn't make sense for `Icon` to be a component AND paint using coordinate.  Instead, if you were going to use a component, `Icon` would simply paint itself (`0x0xwidthxheight`) and the parent container would place it at the specified location

Comment: You will need to call `repaint` to trigger a paint pass when ever you change anything related to the component.  The `paintComponent` will paint the current state

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry but i am a bit confused with the technique you suggested. because i want alot of small icons on the grid and each of those Icons should be a component by themselves as i want them to be `Dragable` in the future and add `mouseListeners` to each component.

Comment: Unless you want to get into the oddities of the drag'n'drop and transferable API, painting the icons within the component is simpler to deal with IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call paintComponent (or any paint) method yourself, ever. This is not how painting works.

The core reasons why a component won't be painted are because:

1. it's size is 0x0
2. it's invisible
3. it's not added to a container that is (indirectly) added to a native peer.

Based on my brief observation, I would say you're suffering from point number 1, in part due to the use of a null layout

Also, remember, when painting a component, the component's `Graphics` context has already been translated so that `0x0` is the top/left corner of the component.  This means, based on your code, you'd most likely be painting beyond the visible bounds of the component any way.

So, you basically have two choices.  Implement your own layout manager, which uses the `Coordinate` information to place the `Icon`s with in the container (which would then need to override `getPreferredSize` in order to provide sizing hints) or, paint it yourself

Which might look something like this...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graph Editor");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(true);
                frame.add(new MyPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Coordinate {

        private int x;
        private int y;

        public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

    }

    public class Icon {

        private Coordinate coordinate;

        public Icon(Coordinate coordinate) {
            this.coordinate = coordinate;
        }

        public Coordinate getCoordinate() {
            return coordinate;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
        }
    }

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private Set<Icon> points;

        public MyPanel() {
            points = new HashSet<>();
            setLayout(null);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
            setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        //gets called by `FILE OPEN` listener for each coordinate
        public void makeIcons(Coordinate obj) {
            points.add(new Icon(obj));
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            for (Icon icon : points) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                Coordinate coordinate = icon.getCoordinate();
                // I'd have a size component associated with the Icon
                // which I'd then use to offset the context by half its
                // value, so the icon is paint around the center of the point
                g2d.translate(coordinate.getX() - 10, coordinate.getY() - 10);
                icon.paint(g2d);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I've not seeded any values, I'm lazy, but that's the basic idea

Comment: Seems like it has fixed it for now. Thanks man. I will keep posting if i encounter other problems. I have seen a lot of your posts regarding `java swing`. You are a Legend.

Comment: @HasnainAli Legend, serial pest, same thing ;)

Comment: Sorry to bother but i have got myself into another problem her. i followed your way and now i have a `paintComponent` in `MyPanel` which calls `paint()` for every icon. But now i have attached a `mouseListener` to each `Icon` in the icon class and the mouse clicks are not triggering any event on the panel.

Comment: No, attach ONE `MouseListener` to `MyPanel`, use it to determine which `Icon` has been selected.  I, personally, would add a `getBounds` method to `Icon` which would return a `Rectangle`, as this is a nice convince method, `contains` which takes a `Point` and returns `true` or `false` if the supplied point is within it's bounds ...